# TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX

Tags: bibtex, errors, texniccenter

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter and it really worked fine.
Unfortunately, without any obvious reason I cannot TeX files anymore.
The following error occurs:

> Bibtex couldn't find `xxx.aux`

Has anyone had the same problem? What goes wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Which versions of MiKTeX and TeXnicCenter do you run? Did you an MiKTeX or Windows update before? Windows had a patch day three days before ...

Comment: Have you run it at least a couple of times?

Comment: These .aux files are supposed to be in the same directory as your project, so they should be there.  Nevertheless, as I mentioned in my last comment, you need to run LaTeX+BibTeX+LaTeX to (or simply run everything 3 times) to generate a complete output